# Texturize robot consisting of STL-files

Tags: gazebo, urdf, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created robots links with CATIA exported them as STL an constructed my own robot with URDF. Now I'm able to move my little mobile robot around the world in Gazebo. Yeah.
Then I mounted an Universal Robot Arm on top of my rover and there where textures on the arm. I looked in the XACRO-Description and found out, they use DAE files with textures to colorize the robots links.
Is it possible (and if with which software) to import STL-files attach textures on it and export it as DAE as easy as possible?
How would you texturize my existing robot with STL files?

Thanks for your help
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297366/texturize-robot-consisting-of-stl-files/) by [vonunwerth](https://answers.ros.org/users/34864/vonunwerth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2018-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-22**:
Please don't delete questions with accepted answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the end i used blender, imported the STLs and attached Materials to it.

Like that: https://all3dp.com/2/blender-how-to-add-a-texture/

---

Originally posted by [vonunwerth](https://answers.ros.org/users/34864/vonunwerth/) with karma: 66 on 2020-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0